# Using "?" to get function details has changed?

Tags: syntax, documentation

I'm running Mathematica 11.0 (I should upgrade, I know) and it used to be that if I entered something like `?Integrate`, Mathematica would output basically a mini version of the [Integrate documentation page.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html)

Then suddenly, it changed and the output is stuff like:

```
System`Integrate
Attributes[Integrate]={Protected,ReadProtected}

Options[Integrate]={Assumptions:>$Assumptions,GenerateConditions->Automatic,PrincipalValue->False}
```

Why did the use of ? change and how do I get it back to its original behavior?

Edit: Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing.  [image] So, I am definitely using just a single question mark.  I should also say that I'm using the xAct package in the notebook, so perhaps it's an issue with the package?

Comment: Are you sure you're just typing `?`? That output would be appropriate for `??`. In general, what does `Information[Integrate]` give?

Comment: Thanks, but I was definitely using a single question mark; this is why I'm very confused. I'll have to check what Information[...] gives when I'm back at work on Monday.

Comment: [Maybe you just have to turn it off and on again.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0)  Seriously though: does restarting Mathematica help?

Comment: I use Mathematica daily.  It started doing this ~ a week ago and has continued consitently since (turning off and on the computer every day).  A re-install could fix it though, for sure.  I wasn't aware that Information[...] was the same as ?... so I'll just try that first on Monday.

Comment: What is $Context? If it is not ``"Global`"``, find out when it changed from ``"Global`"`` to something else.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you must have mistyped your input. Here are four ways you can currently get information on symbol in Mathematica.

[image]

Since Wolfram maintains that `Information` hasn't been modified since it first appeared in V1.0, what you see above should be the same as what you see in V.10 notebooks (providing the usage information or attributes on `Integrate` are the same).

Comment: Thanks, but I was definitely using a single question mark; this is why I'm very confused.  I'll have to check what Information[...] gives when I'm back at work on Monday.

Comment: See edit, please.